# How many switches can I use with a cheap router such as IO in a wired network?

Tags: router, vpn, switch

I have jury rigged ether-network.  It functions ok mostly.  I have something similar to this *I-O DATA WN-DAX1800GR/E WiFi Wireless LAN Router, 11ax, Latest Standards, Wi-Fi6, AX1800,*  in the middle.  I have the wifi shut off and I have 3 switches  distributing the LAN cable.   at most it has 5 connections active at 1 time.  2 of the laptops often have VPN running.   I think the VPN causes the network to destabilize. I am looking for the simplest low-est cost version of creating a stable wire network that doesn't   go down  when 4 or 5  connections are active --  and allows VPN..    I have a used yamaha RTX1100  which works--  it is difficult to configure..  or  is there some recommend? thanks!

Comment: What is your question? (product recommendations are off-topic, also make sure you're not asking about an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/267029))

Comment: Unless you need to have managed switches Netgear GS724TS.  24 port gigabit and get rid of the unnecessary switches.

Comment: So the IO DATA router at the core you think can handle the traffic?  My theory was that the IO DATA is having trouble with the traffic and  the VPN  especially..  but it is just a theory...